# Which lens cap do I need for an Olympus 14-45 f/3.5-5.6 lens?

Tags: olympus, filter-diameter, lens-cap

I am trying to replace the lens cap for my [Olympus 14-45mm f/3.5-5.6 Zuiko Digital](http://slrgear.com/reviews/showproduct.php/product/32) but I'm very confused on which one I can buy.  I am not sure what number I use for the size I need to have.

Comment: I can't find any Olympus 14-4**5** lenses. Do you mean the [Olympus Zuiko Digital ED 14-42mm 1:3.5-5.6](http://www.dpreview.com/products/olympus/lenses/olympus_14-42_3p5-5p6)?

Comment: that's the same problem I am having however the box say 14-45mm

Comment: I looked at the camera itself and the diameter is 58 but I still am not positive how to make sure I am buying the right one

Comment: Ah, turns out the 14-45 did exist as a kit lens for the EVOLT 500, but DPReview just doesn't know about it. I've updated the question a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring-loaded lens caps are designed to grip the filter threads on the lens (or a filter if you have one attached) from the inside.  As such, the cap size you need will be the same as the filter diameter.  (Note that the filter diameter has nothing to do with the focal length(s) of the lens, which is also measured in millimeters.)

Some lenses have a diameter marking (e.g., "⌀ 77 mm") printed on the barrel or the ring that retains the front element.  If there isn't one and you can't find the specifications for your lens, measure the diameter across the filter threads.  The most common sizes are 49, 52, 55, 58, 62, 67, 72 and 77 mm; the size closest to your measurement is the one you want.

The spec sheet linked in the question says 58 mm, so any 58 mm lens cap will work just fine.